# Iterating by index groups in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iterator

I need to send VIN data to an api in groups.  The VINs are grouped by their first three letters called a `wmi`.  The `wmi` is the data frames index.  I'm testing this as I go, and I cannot get just the VINs to print when trying to call by groups. The code below is the closest I got after a few hours of work just trying to get the VINs only to print.

In my actual code, I need to pull a groups by WMI and send those VINs only to the api; then pull the next group and send VINs only to the api.  My loop is incorrect somewhere.

```
#Stack exchange 

import pandas as pd
#develop the data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["vin"], data = ['LHJLC79U58B001633','SZC84294845693987','LFGTCKPA665700387','L8YTCKPV49Y010001',
                                             'LJ4TCBPV27Y010217','LFGTCKPM481006270','LFGTCKPM581004253','LTBPN8J00DC003107',
                                             '1A9LPEER3FC596536','1A9LREAR5FC596814','1A9LKEER2GC596611','1A9L0EAH9C596099',
                                             '22A000018'])
df['wmi'] = df['vin'].str[0:3]
df.set_index('wmi', inplace = True)

for name, group in df.groupby('wmi'):
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in group:
        i = group.vin
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `apply` for grouped data?

```
def do_something(df):
    print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["vin"], data = ['LHJLC79U58B001633','SZC84294845693987',
                                         'LFGTCKPA665700387','L8YTCKPV49Y010001',
                                         'LJ4TCBPV27Y010217','LFGTCKPM481006270',
                                         'LFGTCKPM581004253','LTBPN8J00DC003107',
                                         '1A9LPEER3FC596536','1A9LREAR5FC596814',
                                         '1A9LKEER2GC596611','1A9L0EAH9C596099',
                                         '22A000018'])
df['wmi'] = df['vin'].str[0:3]
df.groupby('wmi').apply(do_something)
```

**OUT:**

```
                  vin  wmi
8   1A9LPEER3FC596536  1A9
9   1A9LREAR5FC596814  1A9
10  1A9LKEER2GC596611  1A9
11   1A9L0EAH9C596099  1A9
                  vin  wmi
8   1A9LPEER3FC596536  1A9
9   1A9LREAR5FC596814  1A9
10  1A9LKEER2GC596611  1A9
11   1A9L0EAH9C596099  1A9
          vin  wmi
12  22A000018  22A
                 vin  wmi
3  L8YTCKPV49Y010001  L8Y
                 vin  wmi
2  LFGTCKPA665700387  LFG
5  LFGTCKPM481006270  LFG
6  LFGTCKPM581004253  LFG
                 vin  wmi
0  LHJLC79U58B001633  LHJ
                 vin  wmi
4  LJ4TCBPV27Y010217  LJ4
                 vin  wmi
7  LTBPN8J00DC003107  LTB
                 vin  wmi
1  SZC84294845693987  SZC
```